# how can we upload image to xml

Tags: android

how to upload images to the XML file using XML parser.Please provide me sample code or example.

Comment: You want to store an image inside an XML file?

Comment: yes, i know but how? if u have any sample code then please help me to solve this.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. XML is a text format. Images are binary. You could do some kind of encoding and place it in an XML file, but what's the point?

Comment: @Saurabh: What goal are you trying to achieve with saving an image to XML? (XML is a text format, images are binary, storing binaries in text is problematic and inefficient, for multiple reasons.)

Comment: basically i m trying to upload the image to the webservice. i know that we can't do this directly in xml, but i can't find any solution.what would be the solution?

Comment: @saurabh .. u can not upload image to xml .. you have to use web services first of of you need to learn xml parsing than any server side file like php/servlet and server side db like mysql/mssql i think use this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558469/problem-for-receved-image-in-php-with-upload-script-android

Comment: @Saurabh the web service should specify what format they expect the data in.

Comment: They expect images in XML format?

Comment: we have to just post the image to the particular URL.so directly image will not be stored in the xml format,so we require to convert into bytes.

Comment: @Saurabh Is there an exact documented requirement? If there is, consider quoting that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class. This will allow you to encode a binary stream to ASCII text which can be then appended in an XML element.

Afterwards, when you need the image, you can decode it once again to its original binary state.

Not that I recommend you to do things like this, since it will be inefficient and slow (my personal guess), but you can if you want.